# Appending linq query of xdocument to list

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Struggling with one aspect of my code that I hope someone could shed some light on.

I'm pulling an xml document multiple times from within a simple foreach loop. I want to append my linq query to a list, but it is rewriting the list each time. Here's the code:

```
IEnumerable<TranList> tList;
foreach (var t in otherList)
{
         //pulling xml data from service here - code not shown
         XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFromService);
         tList = from x in xDoc.Descendants("Items")
         select new TranList
         {
             BusDate = x.Descendants("BusDate").First().Value,
             SeqNum = x.Descendants("SeqNum").First().Value,
             Amount = x.Descendants("Amount").First().Value,
             Credit = x.Descendants("Credit").First().Value
         };
}
```

and here's my xml for reference:

```
<Items>
    <DbAmount>25,465.58</DbAmount>
    <DBCount>296</DBCount>
    <CrAmount>.00</CrAmount>
    <CrCount>0</CrCount>
    <Item>
        <ID>0</ID>
        <BusDate>20090126</BusDate>
        <BlockNum>729</BlockNum>
        <SeqNum>2</SeqNum>
        <RelSeqNum>0</RelSeqNum>
        <Serial />
        <Routing>211690953</Routing>
        <Account>123456789</Account>
        <Amount>30.00</Amount>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Credit>DEBIT</Credit>
        <Onus>TRANSIT</Onus>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    </Item>
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
</Items>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently re-assigning `tList` every time, instead concatenate:

```
tList = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("Items")
        select new TranList
        {
            BusDate = x.Descendants("BusDate").First().Value,
            SeqNum = x.Descendants("SeqNum").First().Value,
            Amount = x.Descendants("Amount").First().Value,
            Credit = x.Descendants("Credit").First().Value
        }).Concat(tList);
```

But why do you need a `foreach` in the first place? You are not even using the loop variable currently so this doesn't make much sense as is.

Comment: In the loop it is repulling new xml data based on values of the loop variable. Left that code out to not clutter it up.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Very simple solution to what I needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
List<TranList> tList = new List<TranList>();

foreach (var t in otherList)
{
     //pulling xml data from service here - code not shown
     XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFromService);
     tList.AddRange(from x in xDoc.Descendants("Items")
     select new TranList
     {
         BusDate = x.Descendants("BusDate").First().Value,
         SeqNum = x.Descendants("SeqNum").First().Value,
         Amount = x.Descendants("Amount").First().Value,
         Credit = x.Descendants("Credit").First().Value
     });
}
```

The important part is that `tList` now is a `List<TranList>` to which you add the query results via `AddRange(...)`.

Comment: Although I used the other solution, I like this one as well. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = from t in otherList
             from x in XDocument.Parse(xmlFromService(t)).Root.Elements("Item")
             select new TranList
             {
                 BusDate = (string)x.Element("BusDate"),
                 SeqNum = (string)x.Element("SeqNum"),
                 Amount = (string)x.Element("Amount"),
                 Credit = (string)x.Element("Credit")
             };
```